# Find the limit of $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Find the limit of $$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}$$

So, I know that $$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0} f(x)=c \Leftrightarrow \forall (x_n)\subseteq D\setminus\{x_0\}, x_n\to x_0: f(x_n)\to c \, (n\to \infty)$$

Let $x_n=\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right), y_n=\left(\frac{1}{n},0\right):$
$$f(x_n)=\frac{\frac{1}{n}^4}{\frac{1}{n}^4}=1\\
f(y_n)=\frac{0}{...}=0\\
\Rightarrow f(x_n)\neq f(y_n)\, (n\to \infty)$$

So the limit doesn't exist. Correct?

Comment: Yes, correct.  The limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ along the path $y=x$ is $1$ while the limit along the path $x=0$ or $y=0$ is $0$.  So, the limit fails to exist.

Comment: @Dr.MV but from the definition of the limit, we should not look the function as the x or y at 0, but around 0, so how can we go on line x=0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is correct.

We have, as $n \to \infty$, $(1/n,1/n) \to (0,0)$,
$$f(1/n,1/n)=\frac{1/n^4}{1/n^4+0} \to 1$$ and we have, as $n \to \infty$, $(1/n,0) \to (0,0)$,
$$f(1/n,0)=\frac{0}{0+1/n^2} \to 0$$
The given limit *does not* exist.

Comment: how can we consider the case where y=0 ?

Comment: @Leth We are alowed to consider this case provided that $(1/n,0)\neq (0,0)$, which is the case as $n \to \infty$.